# Global gain and frame gain in audio and speech processing

Tags: audio, speech-processing, reference-request, terminology

I'm wondering if there is a standard definition for global gain and frame gain in audio and speech processing. I found these terms together with an imprecise definition in a text about bandwidth extension in speech coding. However, I'm not able to find this definition in any other publication, lecture notes, or textbook.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would help if you post the reference. These terms are occasionally used but it's mostly context dependent and I don't think there is a "standard definition".

Comment: Here is the definition given in the text: "Global gain is defined by the ratio of the energy of the original high-band part of each frame of the speech signal to the energy of the synthesized high-band signal. The subframe gain is defined by the ratio of the energy of the original high-band parts of subframes of each frame of the speech signal to the energy of the synthesized high-band signal."

Comment: Sorry, that sounds like it's very a narrow definition that's specific to the text.

Comment: Therefore, I was initially asking whether there is a standard definition ;-)